# Extracting key value pairs from multiple dictionaries in multiple text files using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have 300+ files in a folder each containing 3000+ dictionaries of the form below:

```
{"vol":0.625,"view100":7732,"view50":7732,"view0":7732,"mView100":7732,"mView50":7732,"mView0":7732,"posTop":0,"posBottom":768,"posRight":1024,"posLeft":0,"audio":7732,"inView":1.0,"dur":15070,"full":true,"play":7732,"platform":"ias_i2","timestamp":1519693191,"gmMeasure":true,"gmm":4,"gdr":1,"impId":1861913361,"advId":13505389,"campId":2214346458,"grpId":4532473096,"creativeId":138222749951,"skip":false,"event":"fully_viewable_audible_half_duration_impression","auc":"r","pos":2,"ua":"com.google.ios.youtube/13.06.9 (iPad6,11; U; CPU iOS 11_2_1 like Mac OS X;en_US)","ip":"96.3.52.188","time":1519693200574,"sourceId":2,"channel":"tab","appServerName":"pm01.dal.303net.pvt","doNotTrack":false,"s2s":0}

{"vol":1.0,"view100":8055,"view50":8055,"view0":8055,"mView100":8055,"mView50":8055,"mView0":8055,"posTop":0,"posBottom":360,"posRight":640,"posLeft":0,"audio":8055,"inView":1.0,"dur":15000,"full":false,"play":8055,"platform":"ias_a2","timestamp":1519693191282,"gmMeasure":true,"gmm":4,"gdr":1,"impId":1087849849,"advId":13505389,"campId":2214346458,"grpId":4532473093,"creativeId":138222749951,"skip":false,"event":"fully_viewable_audible_half_duration_impression","auc":"r","pos":1,"ua":"com.google.android.youtube/13.05.52(Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; en_US; SM-J320V Build/NMF26X) gzip","ip":"50.80.2.228","time":1519693200589,"sourceId":2,"channel":"mob","appServerName":"pm01.dal.303net.pvt","doNotTrack":false,"s2s":0}
```

I need to extract a specific K,V pair lets say  and store the entire dictionary containing that pair in a txt file in python.

Here is what I have tried:

```
people = [ {'name': "Tom", 'age': 10}, {'name': "Mark", 'age': 5}, {'name': "Pam", 'age': 7} ] 

def search(name):
    for p in people:
        if p['name'] == name:
            return p search("Pam")
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Ive tried something like this (assuming a small sized dictionary):people = [
{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10},
{'name': "Mark", 'age': 5},
{'name': "Pam", 'age': 7}
]

def search(name):
    for p in people:
        if p['name'] == name:
            return p

search("Pam")    This gives the dictionary but I am not able to extrapolate it to the entire text file and then to the other files in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 distinct problems here:

- how to process 300+ text files containing json string (and not dictionnaries)
- how to identify the dictionary(ies?) containing a specific key, value

The `fileinput` module could solve first part, the json module could transform each line in a Python dict, and you already have the code to search a key, value pair in a dict.

So assuming that `filelist` contains the paths for relevant files (`glob` module could help in building it...):

```
for line in fileinput.fileinput(filelist):
    if len(line.strip()) != 0:       # skip eventual empty lines...
    cur = json.loads(line)
    if cur[key] == value:
        # line contains the text for the dictionary, cur contains the dictionary itself
        # fileinput.filename() contains the name of the file
        # fileinput.filelineno() is the current line
        # for example
        print("Found", key, "->", value, "in", fileinput.filename(),
            "at line", fileinput.filelineno(), ":\n", line)
```

Comment: the first says fileinput.fileinput. is that correct?